# Can this be improved using tortoise and hare algorithm

Tags: linked-list

I am trying to understand linked list in C, I have a program which counts the nodes with value 10 in a circular doubly list. Can I apply tortoise and hare algorithm to this program?, if yes then how? Thanks

```
int count(node *current, node *start, int c)
{
    if(current == NULL)
        return c;
    if((current->value)==10)
        c = c + 1;
    if(current->next == start)
        return c;
    return count(current->next, start,c);
}
```

My Try:

```
int count(node *start, int c)
{

    node *fast = start;
    if(start == NULL)
    return 0;
    if(!(fast=fast->next))
    if((start->roll_no)==10)
        c = c + 1;
    if(fast==start)
        return c;
    return count(start->next,c);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. The algorithm is trivial. Try it yourself.

Comment: Hi leppie, I tried it on my own, but it is always giving 0 as count. Could you help me in figuring out, what I am doing wrong. The edited code is posted above. Thank you for your help and sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This is my c++ version of mine, and working fine.

```
int HasCycle(Node* head)
{
    Node* tr = head;
    Node* hr = tr;
    while(1)
    {
        if(!hr)
            return 0;
        hr = hr->next;
        if(!hr)
            return 0;
        hr = hr->next;
        tr = tr->next;
        if(hr == tr)
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```